# How to use a buttonfield in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, markup

I am using this gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMessages" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" 
    CaptionAlign="NotSet" CellPadding="5" onrowcommand="gvMessages_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Avändare">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# GetSender((int)Eval("Sender"))%>
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ämne">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Head")%>
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Öppna" CommandName="Open" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want a textbox to show the message member of the bound object (Eval("Message")) of the row that has been clicked.

Comment: when does `Message` being set? when you click the row or the button that will fire the `gvMessages_RowCommand`?

Comment: The gridview has a datasource consisting of a list of mail objects. A mailobject has the following members: Message, Reciever, Read, Sender, Head. As you can see, the Sender and Head members are being showed in the grid but I want the Message to be displayed in a textbox when I click the button of that row.

Comment: so, all you really want is a show/hide div that will contain the message ... right?

Comment: Yes. That displays the message of the row button being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

from the comments, and I would suggest to have the show/hide in the client, so you can save a round trip to the server

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMessages" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" 
    CaptionAlign="NotSet" CellPadding="5">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Avändare">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# GetSender((int)Eval("Sender"))%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ämne" DataField="Head" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Avändare">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <button class="btn-showmsg">Öppna</button>
                <div class="message hide">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server"
                         TextMode="MultiLine" Text="<%= Eval("Message") %>" />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and in javascript

```
$(function() {

    $(".btn-showmsg").click(function() {
        var tr  = $(this).closest("tr"), // the <tr>
            msg = tr.find(".message");   // the div wraping the message

        msg.show(); // show it
    });

});
```

Now, the position and the placement of the message, it's all up to you, but I would suggest something like [Bootstrap Modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) to show it.

also, remember to add a style of `.hide { display: none; }`

Comment: sure, but why? why will you waste a roundtrip to the server, to load the entire page again if all you need is right there already?